# How to obtain or craft Pecha Scarf in Pokemon Dusk?

Tags: pokemon-dusk

I already have Pecha berries but I don't know how to craft Pecha Scarf? Can anybody tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Pecha Scarf is crafted by obtaining pecha berries. In Mart shop there is a battle point shop. In battle points section you can buy pecha Berry for 150 battle points each. If you are a battles pro you can just buy 500 berries total cost 75k battle points. Then go to Dark Alley. Make sure you have 3000 coins as well. You can also grow berries in your garden. Go to estate agent to buy your home then plant pecha berries you've go from mart shop.